# Call function stored as class property

Tags: typescript, screeps

I have a class `Process` that takes in a type of object `() => void` in its constructor. Whenever I pass this into the object, all appears fine and well, however later I attempt to call it from a "Kernel" singleton object that iterates over all the `Process[]` objects stored in my `Scheduler` class. How do I properly call this function? Bonus, is there a way to make the function on the `Process` class able to accept other types of functions, perhaps with arguments, outside adding additional properties?

### Process

```
export class Process {
    id: Id<Process>
    run: () => void
    cpuUsed?: number
    priority: ProcessPriority

    constructor(id: Id<Process>, priority: ProcessPriority, task: () => void) {
        this.id = id
        this.priority = priority
        this.run = task
    }
}
```

### Kernel

The idea for this `Kernel` object is to control how often the tasks, added in the scheduler, are actually run. I'm expecting the `executeTasks()` function to properly trigger the `.run()` stored in the map obtained from the scheduler.

```
export class Kernel implements ITaskManager {
    private static _instance?: Kernel
    static getInstance() {
        if (this._instance) return this._instance
        return this._instance = new Kernel()
    }

    scheduler: Scheduler

    executeTasks() {
        console.log("Task count: " + this.scheduler.taskQueue.size)
        for(const value in Array.from(this.scheduler.taskQueue.keys())) {
            let task = this.scheduler.taskQueue.get(value as Id<Process>)
            task?.run()
        }
    }

    kill(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.")
    }

    pause(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.")
    }

    skip(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.")
    }

    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructed scheduler.")
        this.scheduler = new Scheduler()
    }
}
```

### Scheduler

This block contains the function that I'm attempting to call. For the sake of testing and brevity, I've set it up to add the `new Process` in the constructor, namely because I want to be sure I'm doing it correctly.

```
export class Scheduler {
    taskQueue: Map<Id<Process>, Process>

    constructor() {
        this.taskQueue = new Map()
        let tempProcess = new Process("someID" as Id<Process>, ProcessPriority.INDIFFERENT, this.someFunction)
        this.addTask(tempProcess)
    }

    // This is the function I'm attempting to call. 
    someFunction = function(): void {
        console.log("It kinda works.")
    }

    addTask(task: Process) {
        console.log("adding task: " + task.id + " | " + task)
        this.taskQueue.set(task.id, task)
    }

    getTask(id: Id<Process>): Process | undefined{
        return this.taskQueue.get(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `executeTasks()` function. It was iterating over the map improperly. The correct way to iterate over a map is this. It was resulting in a `key` of `0` instead of the expected `"someID"` string.

```
for (let [, value] of this.scheduler.taskQueue) {
    value.run()
}

// OR This

this.scheduler.taskQueue.forEach(x => x.run())
```